# Managing an Item from Listview created by code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listviewitem

I'm learning a lot these days reading posts on stackoverflow, got all my doubts away on java programing with eclipse, but i started to make my custom codes and i got stuck on a situation, i created a clickable listview on code and i want to change the item's text size and align toward the listview layout, any tips?

Obs.: I have only 1 item available by code, this is an experiment.

Thanks in advance

```
package com.example.aulasinterativas;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Menu extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        ListView mlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mlistView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {
                        "Infantil", "1° ano", "2° ano", "3° ano", "4° ano",
                        "5° ano", "6° ano", "7° ano", "8° ano", "9° ano",
                        "1° ano do Ensino Médio", "2° ano do Ensino Médio", "3° ano do Ensino Médio" }));

        mlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                String sText = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                Intent intent = null;
                if (sText.equals("1° ano"))
                    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Menu1ano.class);


                if (intent != null)
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

And my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tile"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="357dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the appropriated xml layout?

Comment: So its an adapter situation? Ill look into it, thanks :)

Comment: Well, the adapter seems to use Textlist to modify it items, but there is no way to change it from code without adding textlist on XML?